# JQuery datepair - getting the ultimate date value

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I have several years of experience of JS programming, and yet after surfing the net, can't find out how to get the ultimate selected date value in this JSFIddle. That is, my goal is to send two datetime objects to my server-side. What is the best practice way to do it ?

http://jsfiddle.net/r75sez35/82/

```
<p id="datetimePicker">
  <input type="text" class="date start" />
  <input type="text" class="time start" /> to
  <input type="text" class="time end" />
  <input type="text" class="date end" />
</p>

$('#datetimePicker .time').timepicker({
  'showDuration': true,
  'timeFormat': 'g:ia'
});

$('#datetimePicker .date').datepicker({
  'format': 'm/d/yyyy',
  'autoclose': true
});

$('#datetimePicker').datepair({
  parseDate: function(input) {
    return $(input).datepicker('getDate');
  },
  updateDate: function(input, dateObj) {
    $(input).datepicker('setDate', dateObj);
    console.log(input);
  }
});
```

Comment: Just concatenate the time and date values together before sending them to the server as strings, then convert them to datetimes on the server.

Comment: The problem is that the strings would be dependent on the format. Which is customized by user

Comment: How are the strings customized by the user? You are using a datepicker for the dates and a timepicker for the time, You are the one controlling the format.